# C# Finding and pressing a button created by JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

Following previously answered question from StackOverflow, I came up with this code to locate and press buttons on a web browser:

```
HtmlElementCollection allButtons = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement button in allButtons) {
            listView1.Items.Add(button.OuterText);
            if (button.OuterText == "Like") {
                button.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
```

The problem is that this code (I think) refers to the page source while I need to find a button created later by Javascript. The button has no ID and it's not inside a table.

I'm currently using .Net Webbrowser class.

Does anyone know a good tutorial of scraping JS data using C# or any other tutorial which could help me achieving my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a javascript that clicks on that button and then inject that script into the webbrowser and run:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement script = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)script.DomElement;
element.text = "function clickOnLike() { var btns = document.GetElementsByTagName('button'); for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++) if(btns[i].InnerHTML == 'Like'){btns[i].click(); break;} }";
head.AppendChild(script);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("clickOnLike");
```

Comment: note that the javascript code I have written may not be accurate, but I just want to give you the idea

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ashkan, This could work but i'm stuck one step behind. I need to first make sure that the button exists while it doesn't have an ID. Can i somehow get the page source After Javascript finished loading? This way i could look for specific words and make sure it exists

Comment: well you can do all of it using javascript. By the way `DocumentCompleted` event filres after document is loaded. you can try that and may be in this event use a timer to wait a bit, like 100 ms. but I think javascript option is better and less messy

Comment: Thanks for the help